# C# check of 2 text boxes have data in them

Tags: c#

I like to check if 2 of the textboxes have data in them. If so, I would like to do some processing.

I have the following code but not sure why it executes even when one of the textboxes is empty:

```
     if (!(string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtUp.Text) && (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtLower.Text)))) 
     {
        // Go here only if both textboxes have data in them

     }
```

Comment: Replace `&&` (and) with `||` (or) and it'll work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try this ie, you are missing to put both the condition in `brackets()` as you want to check both and then `!` them:-

```
if (!((string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtUp.Text) && (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtLower.Text)))))
```

Answer (score 3):

You are missing a `!` in your seccond condition. Should be:

```
                                              here
                                              v
if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtUp.Text) && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtLower.Text)) 
{
   // Go here only if both textboxes have data in them
}
```

Also, the parentheses were messed up

Comment: +1 better than switching to OR because this one short-circuits